# MySQL read replica with particular databases using AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have multiple RDS over AWS with multiple databases with each RDS. Now i want to configure read replica with few databases of different RDS at single destination server. But AWS doesn't allowed me this options, It allows to configure read replica of complete RDS only.
Please help me with your suggestions.
Thank you.